# Sync with Google Drive and Docs

Tags: hard-drive, sync, ios, google-drive, google-docs

I have a few friends who run a number of Google accounts and uses Google Drive (v3.2.2) and Google Docs (v1.1.3.5459) for iOS (8.1) with iPads. One of the friends has created a directory under Google Drive which is shared to the others, with write permissions.

When the others creates a directory, it's synced directly. But when they try to create a document in that folder, the first document will not sync. Only when they create document number two it's get synced and everyone can see it. (The first document is only retained locally on the iPad)

Worked fine last week. Help with this would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Does this happen only when the first file is created by an iOS device? Have you tested it with PCs or other Apple devices?

Comment: Same thing on iphone 5s.
It does work when we create a document through drive.google.com.